# Android Import contacts from phonebook issue

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to import a contacts from the android phonebook. The app works properly on all the phones but fails on HTC phones. My code is below

```
 Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
        startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);


Uri contactUri = data.getData();
                String[] projection = {Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,Phone.NUMBER};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                        .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
                int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                int nameColumn=cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                String number = cursor.getString(column);
                String fName=cursor.getString(nameColumn);
                contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
                contact.put(fName, number);
                eName.setText(fName);
```

As it was on a client phone, I couldnt get to see the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Android has several abstractions for their contacts (Contact <- RawContact <- Data) to be able to seperate different providers (Google, FB, etc.) and to aggregate them. The documentation gives a good overview, how the contacts provider works:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html

I think that your problem is, that you are trying to access data fields in the contacts table. Intent.ACTION_PICK returns the contact uri, which is pointing to the contacts table.

What you need to do is to get the Contacts._ID from the contacts table and then get the data from the ContactsContract.Data table, filtered by the Contacts._ID. You can find sample queries here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html

Answer (score 0):

Was it a crash the user experienced? Might be due to some devices return null in DISPLAY_NAME of NUMBER when there is no name/number (might happend if the device has custom content providers like Skype and such). Some devices return the number in the display_name and some null.

Or was it just that the user couldn't see any contacts? Do you know if the user actually have any? What happens with your code if the contact book is empty for instance.

Comment: I am passing a intent to the Phonebook. The user picks up the contact which is imported to the app.

Comment: Thank for the reply.yes the user is able to see the contact and has picked a contact which has both name n number